# T-SQL string email format issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms-2012

I am trying to build an email and have run into an issue. When the stored procedure runs, I get the following error message.

> Msg 14624, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_send_dbmail, Line 242
>   At least one of the following parameters must be specified. "@body,
>   @query, @file_attachments, @subject".

My code is below but I am adding each of the requested items. I have narrowed down where the breakdown happens. If I pull out the concatenation "+" everything works as expected. But I have done this before with the concatenation so I am not sure what is different.

```
DECLARE @RespPeriod varchar(20)
DECLARE @SubjectLine varchar(100)
DECLARE @ContactEmail varChar(100)
DECLARE @AAEAPVSupplierID int
DECLARE @key varchar(50)
DECLARE @formattedURL varchar(100)
DECLARE @emailBody varchar(max)

DECLARE Curs Cursor 
FOR 
    SELECT theID FROM #temptbl

OPEN Curs

FETCH NEXT FROM Curs INTO @theID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    INTO #temptbl 
    FROM tblmainTbl 
    WHERE theID = @theID 

    DECLARE @isComplete Bit = 1

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #temptbl WHERE Complete = 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @isComplete = 0
    END

    IF @isComplete = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @SubjectLine = 'Testing ' + @RespPeriod + ' Testing.'
        SET @ContactEmail = (SELECT SalesEmail FROM #temptbl WHERE theID = @theID)
        SET @key = (SELECT ResponseKEY FROM #temptbl WHERE theID = @theID)
        SET @formattedURL = 'http://www.something.com/something.aspx?rkey=' + @key
        SET @emailBody = '<html>Dear BlaBlaBla' + @RespPeriod + ' ' +  @formattedURL + '">' + @formattedURL + '</a></html>' 

        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
                    @profile_name = 'SMTPProfile'
                    ,@recipients = @ContactEmail 
                    ,@subject = @SubjectLine
                    ,@body = @emailBody
                    ,@body_format = 'HTML'
    END

    DROP TABLE #temptbl

    FETCH NEXT FROM Curs INTO @theID 
END

CLOSE Curs
DEALLOCATE Curs
```

Comment: From what you posted it is because most of your variables are NULL. When you then concatenate to a string it will be NULL. I have to ask, why are you creating a temp table and dropping it every trip through your loop? There is something very wrong with the way that looping and the temp table are setup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code sample is incomplete (you're lacking the declaration of some of the variables used).  My hunch is one or more of the variable values (maybe @RespPeriod?) is NULL, and when you do the concatenations for the variable assignments used in your `sp_send_dbmail` call, you're passing NULL.

Remember, string + NULL = NULL

Right before your call to the `sp_send_dbmail`, insert these statements...

```
        PRINT '--------------'
        PRINT '@SubjectLine =  ' + ISNULL(@SubjectLine, 'NULL')
        PRINT '@ContactEmail = ' + ISNULL(@ContactEmail, 'NULL')
        PRINT '@key = ' + ISNULL(@key, 'NULL')
        PRINT '@formattedURL = ' + ISNULL(@formattedURL, 'NULL')
        PRINT '@emailBody = ' + ISNULL(@emailBody, 'NULL')
        PRINT '--------------'
```

It should quickly become apparent if this is your cause.  If it is, chase back the individual parts of whatever variables are resolving as NULL until you find the piece that caused the entire string to be NULL.  If it is not, please provide more code so we can look somewhere else.

Comment: As usual, I was missing something dumb. Thank you for pointing it out. I never declared the @RespPeriod.

Comment: Put the above code **immediately** before the `sp_send_dbmail` call. In my case, similar code to check the value of my `@recipient` variable earlier in the code was showing a valid value, but between then and the `sp_send_dbmail` call it was set to `NULL`.